# How to output a missing number in set in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I have a set in C++, and it contains numbers from 0 to n. I wish to find out the number that is missing from 1 to n and output that and if none of them is missing, then output the number (n+1).

For example, if the set contains, `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`, then it should output `8`
If it contains, `0 1 3 4 5 6`, then it should output `2`. 
I made the following code for this, but it always seems to output `0`. I dont know what is the problem.

```
set<int>::iterator i = myset.begin();
set<int>::iterator j = i++;
while (1)
{
    if ( *(j) != *(i)+1 )
    {
        cout<<*(j)<<"\n";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're advancing `i`:

```
set<int>::iterator i = myset.begin(); // <-- i points to first element
set<int>::iterator j = i++;           // <-- j points to first element
                                      //     i points to second!
while (1)
{                                     // so if our set starts with {0, 1, ...}
    if ( *(j) != *(i)+1 )             // then *j == 0, *i == 1, *i + 1 == 2, so this
                                      // inequality holds
```

What you meant to do is have `j` be the *next* iterator after `i`:

```
std::set<int>::iterator i = myset.begin(), j = myset.begin();
std::advance(j, 1);
```

With C++11, there's also `std::next()`:

```
auto i = myset.begin();
auto j = std::next(i, 1);
```

Or, alternatively, just reverse your construction:

```
std::set<int>::iterator j = myset.begin();
std::set<int>::iterator i = j++; // now i is the first element, j is the second
```

Or, lastly, you really only need one iterator:

```
int expected = 0;
for (std::set<int>::iterator it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); 
     ++it, ++expected)
{
    if (*it != expected) {
        std::cout << "Missing " << expected << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, but in order to handle the case when the missing  number is at the end of the set, that is the first example that I gave, how to handle that?

Comment: For starters, the problem is that he is accessing beyond the end of the array.  It's quite possible to write correct code using two iterators (plus the end iterator), although IMHO, it's not the best solution.  But in all cases, you must ensure that all accesses into the set are in bounds.

Comment: In other words, your last version is the best approach. But why confuse issues with a `break`?  Just add the condition to the condition in the `for`, and whatever `expected` is when you leave the loop, that's the value he's looking for.

Comment: In order to handle the above case that I mentioned in the comments, what I did was take a flag variable whose value is initialised to 0. If in case the missing number is in between the array, the flag is set to 1, but if the missing number is at the end of the array, I just print the value of expected.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest stuff: Use `count()` function of `set` to check whether an element is present in set or not.

The `count()` takes an integer argument: The number whose existence in the set is to be checked. If the element is present in set, `count()` returns a non zero value, else it returns `0`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<int> s;
    //I insert 0 - 4 in the set.
    for(int i=0;i < 5; ++i)
        s.insert(i);
    //Let 10 be the 'n'.
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        //If i is NOT present in the set, the below condition will be true.
        if (!s.count(i)) 
            cout<<i<<" is missing!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you access beyond the end of the set if the set is
dense, which is undefined behavior.  Another is that you always output
an element in the set (`*j`, where `j` is an iterator into the set);
according to your description, what you want to output is a value which
isn't in the set.

There are a couple of ways of handling this.  The simplest is probably
just to maintain a variable `expected`, initialized with 0 and
incremented each time.  Something like the following.

```
int
firstAvailable( std::set<int> const& allocated )
{
    int expected = 0;
    for ( auto current = allocated.begin(), end = allocated.end();
            current != end && *current == expected;
            ++ current ) {
        ++ expected;
    }
    return expected;
}
```

If you don't want to return 0 if the list isn't empty, but starts with
some other value, initialize `expected` with the first element of the
set (or with whatever you want to return if the set is empty).

EDIT:

Of course, other algorithms may be better.  For this sort of thing, I usually use a bit map.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original code has already been pointed out in the other answers. You're modifying `i` while assigning `j`. You can fix this by initializing the iterators as:

```
set<int>::iterator i = myset.begin();
set<int>::iterator j = i;
j++;
```

A more elegant solution is to take advantage of the fact that the sum of all values up to `n` is `n * (n + 1) / 2`. You can calculate the sum of the actual values, and subtract it from the full sum to obtain the missing value:

```
int findMissing(const std::set<int>& valSet) {
    int valCount = valSet.size();
    int allSum = (valCount * (valCount + 1)) >> 1;
    int valSum = std::accumulate(valSet.begin(), valSet.end(), 0);
    return allSum - valSum;
}
```

The big advantage of this approach is that it does not rely on using a container where iterators provide the values in sorted order. You can use the same solution e.g. on an unsorted `std::vector`.

One danger to look out for when using this approach is overflow. With 32-bit ints, it will overflow with approximately 2^16 values. It might actually still work if it overflows, particularly if you use `unsigned` instead of `int`, but I did not confirm that.

There's a similar approach that uses the XOR of all values instead of the sum, which does not have the problem with overflow.